# Apparently luggage handlers strike in Spain, how to proceed with my already checked luggage?

Tags: luggage, event-based-effects, ryanair

I'm taking a flight this Friday afternoon to Spain from Berlin, I bought a round trip when I was still on Spain, and checked an extra luggage (15kg).

I came with EasyJet (had an extra luggage also), but I'm returning with Ryanair.
Few days ago, I got an ***Urgent email by Ryanair***, saying that I wouldn't be able to carry my already checked luggage because of this strike and that they are unable to do nothing against that. So now they offer me to have a second ***hand luggage*** (which I don't know if would still able to carry my pre-paid 15kg luggage as *hand luggage* or just another 10 kg *hand luggage*)

Other options they suggest me, is to travel with no checked luggage at all, and they will refund my money (this is not really an option for me since I really need a second luggage), or book another flight in a different date (Is important for me to go this day, so it's really unlikely).

So, my questions are:

- Is there any other kind of possibility of getting my checked luggage even if it's on different date? (Like if I let them put my luggage on another flight, while I go with the first scheduled and they notice me when I can pick it).
- If I just go like if I never read that mail, will they force me to leave my luggage there or just won't be able to take my flight?

I already sent them a message, but no response yet.
I'm really worried about that, because I can't leave my luggage nor want to book another flight.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can't you just carry both the 15kg and the 10kg item as hand luggage? It sounds like that is what RyanAir is offering you (second hang luggage item for free). Unless you have large liquid items you can't carry in hand luggage, just take both bags on the plane with you. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "already checked luggage"? Your bag is with you in Berlin? How can it already be checked several days before the flight departs?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Hand luggage is different when it comes about -what can you carry on them-, also my suitcase (the one i brought from Spain with EasyJet) is not fittable for hand luggage (the size and all), and finally i don't feel like loosing 5kg since i really need the 15kg and even more.

Comment: OK. You didn't explain that your luggage was too large or too heavy :) In that case, agree with SpaceDog, unless you can make it fit hand luggage criteria, you will need to find another option (train, different date, etc.)

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Yes, and also is possible to check a luggage several days before the flight departs (at least is what i did when bought my ticket 3 months ago)

Comment: that's not checking your luggage. 'Checking' your luggage (also called 'checking it in') is the process of taking it to the airport and handing it over. I think what you've done is *pre-pay for checked luggage*, which on a discount airline such as RyanAir may save money versus paying for checking it at the airport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any other kind of possibility of getting my checked luggage even if it's on different date? (Like if I let them put my luggage on another flight, while I go with the first scheduled and they notice me when I can pick it).

They will not put your luggage on a flight you are not on, no airline will as far as I know (but see below for cargo options).

> If I just go like if I never read that mail, will they force me to leave my luggage there or just won't be able to take my flight?

You cannot take your luggage in the hold. They will either let you take it in the cabin (which may not be possible given how much space there normally is). It's also not clear if they'll charge extra, but I suspect not. Additionally if it's a bag that cannot possible fit under the seats or in the bins it's not going in the cabin.

That does leave the options as 'dump the luggage' or don't take the flight.

You say you can't change the day you leave, but can you change *where* you leave from? In articles on this (i.e. [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3107086/Ryanair-baggage-handlers-stage-indefinite-strike-Spain-s-largest-airport-budget-airline-plans-cut-pay-30.html)) it says:

> A Ryanair spokeswoman told MailOnline Travel: ‘All flights to and from Madrid are running as normal, however, customers have been requested to travel with cabin baggage only and have been offered the choice of transferring to alternative flights or alternative airports.

So it looks like you could go to Valencia or Alicante but there's no flights showing for them -- although Ryanair's website may be acting up, there's no flights showing for a lot of destinations.

Your best bet is to talk to Ryanair about it, I would either use their Live Chat service (linked on the [Useful Info](http://www.ryanair.com/en/need-to-know/) page). Or [@Ryanair](https://twitter.com/ryanair) on Twitter. I'd say call but, predictable, I can't find a number. Note that their contact page also currently says:

> Following our recent flight disruptions we are receiving high volumes of correspondence. If you have submitted a claim you should receive a response shortly. Please do not resubmit your correspondence as it may further delay our response to you.

So they should still respond to your message *but* you probably want something more interactive in this case.

Your other alternatives are to ship the luggage back, looks like DHL would do it for around 32 Euro ([price list](https://www.dhl.de/en/paket/preise/preise-international.html)). [FedEx](https://www.fedex.com/ratefinder/standalone?method=getQuickQuote) are coming up as around 100 Euro, no price list that I can find just a 'quote' thing but there may be cheaper options.

There's no DHL office in Berlin Schönefeld but there's a list of [other cargo handlers](http://www.berlin-airport.de/en/business-partners/airlines-and-ground-services/air-cargo/service-providers/forwarding-agents-and-cargo-handling/index.php) who may be able help.

Alternatively, you're going back to Madrid, which is doable via train if you have no other option. But I'd ship the baggage back and offset the cost with the refund.

Comment: Thanks for the specific answer!, going to another airport is not possible for me, and I don't know if they would cost me the redirection to Madrid (if they ever plan to do).
One last question, since the strike is undefined until now, are they obligate to refund all my money if we can't agreed another 'near' flight date?

Note: I think you missread that im going back to Madrid from Berlin, but doesn't really matter.

Comment: I edited my question to fix the cities, you're correct I got that the wrong way round. I'm honestly not sure if they're obligated to refund the entire flight, since they're offering alternatives and the extra baggage could be considered a 'service' and not part of the get-passenger-from-a-to-b. Also the strike could arguably by "out of Ryanair's control". There's more in their [FAQ pages](https://www.ryanair.com/en/questions/what-happens-if-my-flight-is-cancelled-by-ryanair/)